# Run a java app on semaphore

Tags: java, deployment, semaphore

I have added my app to [semaphore](https://semaphoreci.com). How can I run my app there?
I see only build there. But I dont know how can I run it.

Comment: Please follow their instruction on how to run your app, and if you face some problem, you can ask a question about it here.

Comment: @BheshGurung I didnt found info about it

Comment: You can read the [documentions here](https://semaphoreci.com/docs) and some [tutorials here](https://semaphoreci.com/community/tags/java).

Comment: Thank you, But I have already founded it, but I dont understand how can I run app in this service